# Can't obtain variable

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to prove the following simple theorem I've come up with, that:

> A point is on the boundary iff any small enough ball around that point contains points both in S and out of S.

Below I've managed to do the forward direction but I'm stuck on the backwards direction.

Using the same approach fails on the last step, the goal is close but not quite there, and I'm not sure what to do here:

```
lemma frontier_ball: "x ∈ frontier S ⟷
  (∃r>0. (∀δ>0. δ<r ⟶ ((ball x δ) ∩ S ≠ {} ∧ (ball x δ) ∩ -S ≠ {})))"
  (is "?lhs = ?rhs")
proof
  {
    assume "?lhs"
    hence "x ∉ interior S ∧ x ∉ interior (-S)" by (auto simp: frontier_def interior_complement)
    hence "∀δ>0. ((ball x δ) ∩ S ≠ {} ∧ (ball x δ) ∩ -S ≠ {})" by (auto simp: mem_interior)
    then have "?rhs" by (simp add: Orderings.no_top_class.gt_ex)
  }
  {
    assume "¬?lhs"
    hence "x ∈ interior S ∨ x ∈ interior (-S)" by (auto simp: frontier_def interior_complement)
    hence "∃δ>0. ball x δ ∩ S = {} ∨ ball x δ ∩ -S = {}" by (auto simp: mem_interior)
    then have "¬?rhs" by (simp add: subset_ball)
  }
qed
```

I tried to tell isabelle how to obtain such a delta but it's stuck on the obtain step:

```
lemma frontier_ball: "x ∈ frontier S ⟷
  (∃r>0. (∀δ>0. δ<r ⟶ ((ball x δ) ∩ S ≠ {} ∧ (ball x δ) ∩ -S ≠ {})))"
  (is "?lhs = ?rhs")
proof
  {
    assume "?lhs"
    hence "x ∉ interior S ∧ x ∉ interior (-S)" by (auto simp: frontier_def interior_complement)
    hence "∀δ>0. ((ball x δ) ∩ S ≠ {} ∧ (ball x δ) ∩ -S ≠ {})" by (auto simp: mem_interior)
    then have "?rhs" by (simp add: Orderings.no_top_class.gt_ex)
  }
  {
    fix r::real
    assume "¬?lhs ∧ r>0"
    hence "x ∈ interior S ∨ x ∈ interior (-S)" by (auto simp: frontier_def interior_complement)
    then obtain r2 where "r2>0" and "ball x r2 ∩ S = {} ∨ ball x r2 ∩ -S = {}" by (auto simp: mem_interior)
    then obtain δ where "δ>0 ∧ δ<r ∧ δ<r2" by auto

  }
qed
```

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can just construct such a δ. If you have `r > 0` and `r2 > 0` you want some `δ` that fulfils `0 < δ ≤ r2` and `0 < δ < r`, why not just use `min r2 (r/2)`? You can define `δ` to be that and then you can prove the properties you want:

```
    def δ ≡ "min r2 (r/2)"
    with r2 A have δ: "δ > 0" "δ < r" "δ ≤ r2" by auto
    with r2 have δ': "ball x δ ∩ S = {} ∨ ball x r2 ∩ -S = {}" using subset_ball[OF δ(3)] by auto
```

Or, a bit more direct:

```
lemma frontier_ball: "(x :: 'a :: {metric_space}) ∈ frontier S ⟷
  (∃r>0. (∀δ>0. δ<r ⟶ ((ball x δ) ∩ S ≠ {} ∧ (ball x δ) ∩ -S ≠ {})))"
  (is "?lhs = ?rhs")
proof -
  {
    assume "?lhs"
    hence "x ∉ interior S ∧ x ∉ interior (-S)" by (auto simp: frontier_def interior_complement)
    hence "∀δ>0. ((ball x δ) ∩ S ≠ {} ∧ (ball x δ) ∩ -S ≠ {})" by (auto simp: mem_interior)
    then have "?rhs" by (simp add: Orderings.no_top_class.gt_ex)
  }
  moreover
  {
    assume lhs: "¬?lhs"
    {
      fix r :: real assume r: "r > 0"
      from lhs have "x ∈ interior S ∨ x ∈ interior (-S)" 
        by (auto simp: frontier_def interior_complement)
      then obtain δ where "δ > 0" "ball x δ ∩ S = {} ∨ ball x δ ∩ -S = {}" 
        by (auto simp: mem_interior)
      with r have "min δ (r/2) > 0" "min δ (r/2) < r" 
        "ball x (min δ (r/2)) ∩ S = {} ∨ ball x (min δ (r/2)) ∩ -S = {}" using subset_ball by auto
      hence "∃δ>0. δ < r ∧ (ball x δ ∩ S = {} ∨ ball x δ ∩ -S = {})" by blast
    }
    hence "¬?rhs" by blast
  }
  ultimately show ?thesis by blast
qed
```

For the record, I would avoid doing things like `assume "A ∧ B"`. Do `assume "A" "B"` instead. That gives you two facts that you can work with directly, instead of having them wrapped up with a HOL conjunction in one fact.